# rp_filter kernel setting precedence

Tags: linux-kernel

When rp_filter kernel setting is configured with different boolean, which takes precedence? all.rp_filter or interface.rp_filter?

net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 0

Answer (score 0):

The *default* property is not involved in this.

For *all* and *eth0* [Documentation about `rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1555) says:

> ```
>   The max value from conf/{all,interface}/rp_filter is used
>   when doing source validation on the {interface}.
> ```

So here highest value takes precedence:

```
max(conf/all/rp_filter,conf/eth0/rp_filter)=max(1,0)=1
```

[SRPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2) is thus in effect on *eth0* (and all other interfaces except those having `rp_filter=2` which would get [Loose RPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.4) behavior instead).

The interaction between `all/rp_filter` and its per-interface matching property is not the only behavior existing, documentation should be checked for each property.

The only role of the value set to *default* and thus `default/rp_filter` is to be inherited by newly created interfaces. This is [documented here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n2038):

> ```
> ``conf/default/*``:
>   Change the interface-specific default settings.
>
>   These settings would be used during creating new interfaces.
> ```

Note that when moving an interface from a network namespace to an other, the per-interface properties will inherit their new *default* settings which could be different in the new namespace: it's as if the interface was just created there.